# Copy a File Without a Confirmation Dialog

Tags: c#, vb.net, copy, hidden

I have a video editing app. If a process completes then I would like to have the app copy the video to the user folder; however, if i use this command:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(TempVid, OutVid, True)
```

then Windows shows a copy dialog box. I would like a 'hidden' copy of the videos.
How can I copy the file without having a pop-up confirmation box appear?

Comment: This method does not usually display a dialog. Can you either describe the dialog which is displayed, or else post a link to an image of the dialog?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I don't understand. @JohnSaunders is right. This code should not produce a popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing to stop you using more detailed calls to [open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) both input and output files, continuously [reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from one and [writing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.write%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the other, stopping when the source file has been exhausted, then [closing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (or [disposing of](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.dispose%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) both.

Granted it's a little more cumbersome than a simple `File.Copy` call but that's the price you may have to pay more greater control.

But you may want to *check* which calls you're actually using. From memory, the `System.IO` ones don't provide a dialog box, you have to use the `FileSystem` ones for that (such as [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc165446%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).

If you're absolutely *sure* you have enough memory to hold the entire file without issues, you can just use something like:

```
Dim MyFileContent() as Byte = File.ReadAllBytes (SourceFileName)
File.WriteAllBytes (DestFileName, MyFileContent)
```

But I tend to prefer the piecemeal (e.g., 1M at a time) to ensure your application doesn't fall to bits with truly huge files.